# Error on entering value in a cell through data table in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I tried the following code to enter value in a cell to get the value from data table. But I get an error. Below is error:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView: 
>   System.Exception: 0.91 is not a valid value for Int32. --->

I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO ELIMINATE THIS ERROR. NEED HELP.

EDIT:-

```
private void DataGrid_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {if (DataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)
            {
                string getprice = "SELECT " + DataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + " FROM " +
                    "" + DataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "_Mstr " +
                    "WHERE Size1 = '" + DataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "'";
                DataTable dt = globalData.q.select(getprice);
                double check;
                if (double.TryParse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), out check))
                {
                    DataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And your code is..? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: what is the data type of 'Size1'?

Comment: edited the question. @wizzardz: Size1 is 'Text'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your SQL is a double while you expect an int.
Either change the data type or force the conversion (I.e. with Convert.ToInt32(xxx) instead of double.Parse)

Comment: I tried to convert.ToInt32(xxx). But it rounds the value. The value is double and I expect double. The database is MS Access 2007.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to provide more info (i.e. stack trace and gridview markup)

Comment: the rest of the error is: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. 
  at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, 
NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) 
  at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, 
NumberFormatInfo info)
  at System.ComponentModelInt32Converter.FromString(String value, 
NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)
 at System.ComponentMcdel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeD 
escriptorContext context, Culturelnfo culture, Object value)

Comment: And last part is: --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeD 
escriptorContext context, Culturelnfo culture, Object value)
 at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
 at Systern.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.Pu 
shValue(Int32 boundColumnIndexInt32 columnIndexInt32 rowIndex. 
Object value) 
To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

Comment: Is the datasource a Dataset/Datatable? If so can you check the column data type?

Comment: Datasource is a DataTable. Its MS Access 2007 database. And column data type is 'Number'(required value data type).

Comment: What about the Gridview.Datasource? Are you using a table adapter or what? Can you post the gridview markup?

Comment: string query = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";
            connection = new OleDbConnection(globalData.connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
            sCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            sAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sCommand);
            sBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
            sDs = new DataSet();
            sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Table");
            sTable = sDs.Tables["Table"];
            connection.Close();
            DataGrid.DataSource = sTable;
            DataGrid.ReadOnly = true;

Comment: btw its a winform application.

Comment: Ok, so try to breakpoit the row "connection.Close()", right click "quickwatch" on sTable variable and check int the Columns property the type of the Columns the OleDbDataAdapter has autogenerated. Probably there is a problem and you need to change the type.

Comment: I checked. You are right. OleDbDataAdapter has autogenerated datatype to Int32. But I want Double. How to do taht?

Comment: Solved. I changed data type from the design view of the table in Access. thanks Stefano.